# How to install NCL and Ferret on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I have started to use Ubuntu a few months ago. I want to install 'Ferret' and 'NCAR Command Language' to my computer but I don't know how. Are there any way to install them on Ubuntu?

Before I started to use Ubuntu I used Fedora for a while and on Fedora I could install them easily. Am I doing something wrong or they are just not working on Ubuntu? These programs are important for me because I'm a meteorological engineer student and I'm using these programs frequently.

Comment: Here websites of these programs:
[NCL](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/) and
[Ferret](http://www.ferret.noaa.gov/Ferret/)

Answer (score 3):

Now you can install ncl through apt-get in Ubuntu 14.04. It has a bug though. Bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ncl/+bug/1329691 . You have to do some linking.

```
sudo apt-get install ncl-ncarg
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ncarg /usr/lib/ncarg
```

And you can start using ncl inside 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

For Ferret, [this guide](http://davies-barnard.co.uk/2011/08/installing-ferret-noaa-onto-ubuntu/) gives detailed (and probably outdated) installation instructions. Unfortunately, it seems no `.deb` files are available.

To get you started:

1. [Download the source code](http://ferret.pmel.noaa.gov/Ferret/downloads/downloading-ferret-source-code)
2. `mkdir ferret_install; cd ferret_install`
3. `tar -xvzf ../fer_source.tar.gz`
4. `cd FERRET`
5. `less README_build_ferret` (and read installation instructions).

Alternatively, you could download `.rpm` package and install it using alien.

```
sudo apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
sudo alien rpm_filename.rpm
sudo dpkg -i rpm_filename.deb
```

Probably at least some dependencies will fail, and you have to install those manually.

---

For NCL, Debian packages are [available](http://www.ncl.ucar.edu/Download/list_of_binaries.shtml). Download appropriate package (either 32bit or 64bit), and install it with `dpkg -i package_filename.deb`. I couldn't test this as they require registeration before downloading is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Ferret is now on main Ubuntu Repository. It can be installed as:

```
sudo apt-get install ferret
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the ferret you are looking for. The visualization package is 'ferret-viz' so:

```
sudo apt-get install ferret-viz
```

'ferret' in Debian/Ubuntu is GNU Ferret, a different package.

rgds
Alastair McKinstry, ferret-viz and NCL maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

The ferret software available under Ubuntu's apt-get is different from NOAA's Ferret.

Here is a short guide to installing Ferret and PyFerret on a Linux system.
Install following first (In Fedora using dnf or Ubuntu Synaptic Manager)

```
PyQt4.x86_64
PyQt5.x86_64(python-qt5.x86_64)
gcc-gfortran.x86_64
scipy.x86_64
numpy.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk
libgfortran
libcurl
pango
cairo
```

Go to the link https://github.com/NOAA-PMEL/PyFerret/releases
and get the link of the required version of pyferret.

```
mkdir -p ~/pkgs
cd ~/pkgs
wget https://github.com/NOAA-PMEL/PyFerret/releases/download/v7.2.1-final/pyferret-7.2.1-RHEL7-64.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.pmel.noaa.gov/ferret/pub/data/fer_dsets.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.pmel.noaa.gov/ferret/pub/rhel6_64/fer_environment.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.pmel.noaa.gov/ferret/pub/rhel6_64/fer_executables.tar.gz
```

Move them to the following directory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/pyferret
sudo mv pyferret-7.2.1-RHEL7-64.tar.gz /usr/local/pyferret
sudo mv fer_*tar.gz /usr/local/pyferret
cd /usr/local/pyferret
```

Extract them all

```
for f in *.gz
do
sudo tar -zxvf $f
done
```

Run Finstall

```
cd pyferret-7.2.1-RHEL7-64
sudo ./bin/Finstall
```

Answer for the first query

/usr/local/pyferret/pyferret-7.2.1-RHEL7-64

Answer for the second query
/usr/local/pyferret

Answer for the third query
/usr/local/pyferret

Type s for bash linking

Type python2.7 as desired version of python

```
source /usr/local/pyferret/ferret_paths
```

keep this path in .bashrc if needed.

Now for installing ferret

```
cd /usr/local/pyferret
sudo ./bin/Finstall
```

/usr/local/pyferret is the answer to all the questions except for ferret_paths directory which is

/usr/local

```
source /usr/local/ferret_paths
```

keep this path in .bashrc if needed

Now both ferret and pyferret commands should be working.

Troubleshooting:

1. Had problem with libgfortran.so.3 not being found by pyferret. Problem is, in fedora27, the latest gcc-gfortran 7 only gives libgfortran.so.4. I could not install any version of gcc-gfortran so that if gives libgfortran.so.3 (using rpms wrecked some existing packages). I took libgfortran.so.3 and libgfortran.so.3.0.0 from another system (Ubuntu 16.04.3) directly and kept them under ~/pkgs/libs and then pyferret worked with following command.
   export `LD_PRELOAD=~/pkgs/libs/libgfortran.so.3:~/pkgs/libs/libopenblas.so.0;pyferret -nojnl`
   you can put an alias in as
   alias pf='export LD_PRELOAD=~/pkgs/libs/libgfortran.so.3:~/pkgs/libs/libopenblas.so.0;pyferret -nojnl'
2. If some package versions differ, try liking the required one in the following way.

   sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/libreadline.so.7.0 /usr/lib64/libreadline.so.6
   sudo ln -sf /usr/lib64/libhistory.so.7.0 /usr/lib64/libhistory.so.6
3. Some more packages may be required(apt-get in case of Ubuntu)

   sudo dnf install libpng15.x86_64
   sudo dnf install libpng12.x86_64
4. Add LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your ~/.bashrc

   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/:/usr/lib64/:/usr/local/pyferret/ext_func/libs/:/usr/local/pyferret/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyferret/